# How to hide dropdown menu when clicked anywhere on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, menu, hide

I have this code that does that.  The only thing issue is that I have to click **twice** to open the dropdown after I've hidden it.  Can you take a look at my code and tell me how I can fix it so that I only have to click the toggle **once** to open the dropdown?

```js
     < script >
      $(function() {
        var menuVisible = false;
        $('#toggle').click(function() {
          if (menuVisible) {
            $('#drop-down').css({
              'display': 'none'
            });
            menuVisible = false;
            return;
          }
          $('#drop-down').fadeIn(400).css({
            'display': 'block'
          });
          menuVisible = true;
        });

        $('#drop-down').click(function() {
          $(this).fadeOut(400).css({
            'display': 'none'
          });
          menuVisible = false;
        });
      });


    $(document).click(function(e) {
      var container = $("#toggle");
      if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
        $("#drop-down").hide();
        var menuVisible = false;
      }
    }); < /script>
```

```html
<div id="toggle"></div>
<div id="drop-down">
  <ul>
    <li>heading 1</li>
    <li>heading 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Post some html too please

Comment: This should show the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/sc3zLzqL/ if you click close the dropdown by clicking somewhere outside, you will have to click the red box twice to re open it

Comment: I've added the html code.  Also Frank's example is exactly what I'm talking about.

Comment: as shown in the answer below in your javascript code you are missing a var menuVisible = false; therefore you are hiding the object, but you forget about setting your variable. By clicking once - the variable is set, as in the upper half of the code. By clicking a second time, it fades in again, because it's now properly set

Comment: How does one click on the (empty) `#toggle` element? If you combine your code into one snippet (JavaScript/jQuery in the JavaScript pane, HTML in the HTML pane and CSS in the CSS pane) then the 'run snippet' should reproduce your problem (but remember to include jQuery as well, from the `<select>` on the top left of the editor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a var menuVisible = false; at the bottom case. If you hide it by clicking somehwere else on the document you will need to set your variable too

This will do the trick: https://jsfiddle.net/sc3zLzqL/1/

```
if ($('#drop-down').css("display") != "none")
```

will not require the variable

Comment: I have multiple different drop downs in the header. I have this code in the footer.  Could it have something to do with where I have this code placed?

Comment: sry for that - i added a jsfiddle instead - this now works (tested) if you dont check for the variable, but the display statement. The example before didnt work, because the variable wasnt global

Comment: For multiple uses you will need to use classes instead of Id's and refer to them by this